# ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS stop showing wifi adapter?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04

So one day I opened my laptop and it stopped showing wifi and the error message was wifi adapter not found. I try to fix that using pre existing solutions like mentions in this form didn’t work for me. I tried to reinstall the wifi driver from the additional driver menu. It showing me this specific error:

```
Error while applying changes 

pk-client-error-quark: Error while installing package: installed bonwl-kerneksource package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10 (03)
```

Since I had a pretty specific issue, I created a new question.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tArbH.png)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2442975&p=13959089#post13959089

```
apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
apt-get install broadcom-sta-source
apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
apt-get install broadcom-sta-common
```

after this steps restart your machine.